# Comparing 2 arrays for content equality

Tags: ruby

I want to compare two arrays, but `assert_equal` raises an error:

```
No visible difference in the Array#inspect output.
You should look at the implementation of #== on Array or its members.
```

Here is my test:

```
describe Post do
    before do
        @draft = Post.new('test-draft', draft = true)
        @post = Post.new('2014-10-31-test-post')
    end

    describe '.drafts' do
        it 'returns an array of unpublished posts' do
            actual = Post.drafts           
            assert_equal [@draft], actual
        end
    end
end
```

Here are my two arrays, they are identical in content, but have different memory locations.

```
[
    [0] #<Post:0x0000000851a178 @file_name="test-draft", @draft=true>
]
[
    [0] #<Post:0x0000000851a538 @file_name="test-draft", @draft=true>
]
```

How can I compare my two arrays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your Post class doesn't have a `==` operator of its own, so no two Post objects can be equal. I think you'll want to give Post some idea of equality.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to see if the values are correct you can implement a helper like method that would implement something like

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = [1,2,3]

((a - b) + (b - a)).empty?
#=> true
```

eg

```
def arrays_equal_values?(a, b)
    ((a - b) + (b - a)).empty?
end
```